# More efficient way to produce an array with all permutations?

Tags: javascript

```
const permutation = (x, y, z) => {
    let array = [];
    for (let i=0; i<=x; i++) {
        for (let j=0; j<=y; j++) {
            for (let k=0; k<=z; k++) {
                console.log(`pushing ${[i,j,k]}`)
                array.push([i,j,k])
            }
        }
    }
    return array
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of writing this function?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in terms of "more efficient"? Less code? Less computational complexity? More general?

Comment: Permutations are necessarily expensive to compute because there's just so many of them! It's rare for a computer program to actually go through all permutations of a set because it's often physically impossible (at least not without a billion-dollar supercomputer or with quantum computing qubits) so instead programs use smart techniques to reduce the set of data to work-through (such as using Rainbow Tables). So anyway - **what problem are you originally trying to solve?**

Comment: yeah question wasn't very clear sry, I meant like less code